# Manipulating S4 Classes

Tags: r, r-s4

```
Example of the problem - class.a has slots 1, 2, 3 
and inherits from class c (4, and 5).  
The slots in class (1, 2, 3) are passed to function.b as variables. 
the output of function b is as class.c.  So now I have the following.



class.a 
   slot 1  a value
   slot 2  a value
   slot 3  a value
   slot 4  empty
   slot 5  empty

   class.c
   slot 4 a result
   slot 5 a result
```

Can class.c simply be merged into class.a?  If so, how?  I have searched documentation and
   I have looked a virtual and superclasses.
   I cannot find anything on merging classes together

Here is the code that creates the classes -

```
setClass("BondDetails",
       representation(
       Cusip = "character",
       ID = "character",
       BondType = "character",
       Coupon = "numeric",
       IssueDate = "character",
       DatedDate = "character",
       StartDate = "character",
       Maturity = "character",
       LastPmtDate = "character",
       NextPmtDate = "character",
       Moody = "character",
       SP = "character",
       BondLab  = "character",
       Frequency = "numeric",
       BondBasis = "character",
       Callable = "character",
       Putable = "character",
       SinkingFund = "character"))

setClass("BondCashFlows",
     representation(
     Price = "numeric",
     Acrrued = "numeric",
     YieldToMaturity = "numeric",
     ModDuration = "numeric",
     Convexity = "numeric",
     Period = "numeric",
     PmtDate = "Date",
     TimePeriod = "numeric",
     PrincipalOutstanding = "numeric",  
     CouponPmt = "numeric",
     TotalCashFlow = "numeric"))

 setClass("BondTermStructure",
     representation(
     EffDuration = "numeric",
     EffConvexity = "numeric",
     KeyRateTenor = "numeric",
     KeyRateDuration = "numeric",
     KeyRateConvexity = "numeric"))

 setClass("BondAnalytics",
     contains = c("BondDetails","BondCashFlows", "BondTermStructure"))
```

BondDetails is stored information
BondCashFlows is calculated using inputs from bond details
BondTermStructure is calculated using inputs from bond details and bondcashflows

I need to get them all into BondAnalytics so I can create a method of output and I just
can't seem to get it right how are these turned into a superclass

Comment: You could rewrite function b to take an object of class a, assign the results to slot 4 and 5, then return the object again?

Comment: Classes can be set up to "inherit" but I do not see a sufficiently explained notion of what "merging" would mean to be able to answer this question. Code.... we need code.

Comment: There are about 700 lines of code covering three functions that are passing variables from S4 objects.  I have no idea how that software could even be posted here.  By merging I mean that I have a superclass that has named slots and also inherits from two other classes.  The software runs the other functions and produced results for the other class (not super class).  So, I was thinking these classes must be smart enough to simply plug into the right superclass slot.  Now, I don't think so it looks like they must be assigned one at a time

Comment: I think you are right Manetheran, but then what is point of having classes inherit from one another.  Just set up a big class(?)

Comment: Unless you have situations where it is meaningful to have `class c` by itself, then there is no point having it as a separate parent class.

Comment: class a is a object database (?) that has been serialized out.  It holds static data on a fixed income security, coupon, first, next pmt, and maturity, etc.. class c is the results of analysis based on price term structure etc.. so it changes every time.  Both need to joined and passed to a function that calculated key rate duration and convexity, the results of which are combined with the previous.  So, it is building the analytics for the bond valuation engine. I think I need to conquer these classes.

Comment: then the slots of class c should never be in class a? It seems like a bad idea to store a serialized database for each analysis. You could just pass the analytics results to function b, and a hook to the database A, then create the relevant query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what those 700 other lines of code do... By default the `initialize` method for S4 classes is a copy constructor, with unnamed arguments taken as instances of base classes. Maybe you mean that you have something like (my classes A, B, C don't correspond to your classes, but somehow the naming seems to make more sense for my understanding of your problem)

```
.A <- setClass("A", representation(a="numeric"))
.B <- setClass("B", representation(b="numeric"))
.C <- setClass("C", contains=c("A", "B"))
```

`.A(...)` is the automatically generated constructor for the "A" class, etc; `.A(...)` creates a new instance of the class "A" and then calls `initialize` (i.e., the copy constructor) with the new instance and arguments `...`. One possibility is that you have an instance of "A" and an instance of "B", and you'd like to construct and instance of "C"

```
a <- .A(a=1)
b <- .B(b=2)
```

with

```
> .C(a, b)              # Construct "C" from base classes "A" and "B"
An object of class "C"
Slot "a":
[1] 1

Slot "b":
[1] 2
```

Another possibility is that you already have an instance of "C", and you'd like to update the values to contain those from an instance of "B"

```
b <- .B(b=2)
c <- .C(a=1, b=3)
```

and then

```
> initialize(c, b)     # Copy c, replacing slots from 'B' with 'b'
An object of class "C"
Slot "a":
[1] 1

Slot "b":
[1] 2
```

Comment: Got it, that is right I have an instance of a then b and would like to create c. thanks -Glenn

Comment: Tried the initialize, still its off a little.  I have class a, b, and c.  superclass contains a, b, and c. a is stored values, b is a result of a function call using a inputs, and c is the result of a function call using inputs from a and b.  I just can't seem to create the superclass.

Comment: Might the use of `?setClassUnion` be useful in this instance?

Comment: @ctbrown Class unions are used when one wishes to create a class that unites two unrelated class hierarchies, whereas here all the classes seem to be in a single hierarchy. Class unions are very weird beasts (to me), and I seldom have use for them.